# How to stop exception html being returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am testing a rails api-only app by sending requests to the development server from a test app.  Sometimes when I generate an exception it triggers an exception that returns a page of html giving details of the exception.  The start of it looks  like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
      color: #333;
      margin: 0px;
    }
```

This verbose page makes it difficult to see what is happening when looking at the test app. Is there any way to get the api app to return a json response when it hits an exception?

Comment: `better_errors` is not part of the default stack, so you'll probably need to explain more precisely what you're seeing

Comment: OK, looking at the page more carefully it is not a better_errors page but an standard exception page.  I will edit the question to correct this and provide more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails doesn't have any built-in JSON exception format, but you can use [`rescue_from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) to catch exceptions and return a response of your choosing:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  rescue_from RuntimeError do |ex|
    render json: { success: false, error: ex.class.name, message: ex.message }, status: 500
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In `application_controller.rb` or the controller file that is relevant, write something like:

```
rescue_from WhatEverExceptionClassToBeCaught do |e|
  render json: some_json_expression
end
```